# Can I use custom collectionview instead segment control in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to implement a selection like a segment control but custom view. I need to know if I use collection view instead of segment control, **It will take resource or memory more than use segment control ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, the difference would be negligible unless you do something really wrong.

A segment control uses an insignificant amount of memory and a collection view is specifically designed to limit the memory it uses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use it for static menu not dynamic and no reload data on runtime. Maybe I will use collectionview.